# Can't login Ubuntu 20.04 due to wrong language

Tags: 20.04, login, update-manager, language-support, default

I downloaded the update just yesterday.
I use two languages in my system, both English and Greek, with Greek being the default language.

My password consists of latin characters, so, to my surprise, the keyboard layout is set to greek and only greek, could not change, even when I selected the english option with my mouse on the top right of the screen.

As I googled my question I saw many people resolving this on older versions by pressing `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `F1/F2/F3` and happily loging in their device.

This though did not seem to word for me either, as, when I am on the black screen and asked to put in my username, the language continues to be greek and is impossible to change.

Has anyone else come across this issue?

Edit: The onscreen keyboard doesn't seem to appear and logging in from the latest revocery did not seem to get my password either.

Comment: The discussion at [bug #1725676](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1725676) may give you some guidance. Somehow you probably need to edit `/etc/default/keyboard` to include the `us` layout.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the system language does not necessarily change the keyboard settings.
When logging in, try using the onscreen keyboard - > click on the little flag bellow and try changing the keyboards setings from there.

Or after logged in from the tty (alt F1-F3 black screen terminal), go to settings, Languages - Input sources and add/change to english input.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the onscreen keyboard doesn't seem to work either.
Edit: I tried to login on root from the latest recovery mode but it seems to be writing greek again...